# Convexity of a ball in any normed space and in any metric space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

I would like to show that an open (and closed) ball in a normed space is convex.

Consider $(X,\lVert\rVert)$ a normed space and $B(X_0, r)$ an open ball centered in $X_0\in X$.

Take $X_1\in B(X_0, r)$, $X_2\in B(X_0, r)$ and $s\in[0,1]$

Clearly we have : $\lVert sX_1 + (1-s)X_2 - X_0\rVert = \lVert sX_1 - sX_0 + (1-s)X_2 -(1-s)X_0\rVert $

$ =\lVert s(X_1 - X_0) + (1-s)(X_2 - X_0)\rVert\leq s\lVert X_1 - X_0\rVert + (1-s)\lVert X_2 - X_0\rVert < sr + (1-s)r = r $

In the same way we conclude for a closed ball in $X$.

<s>I would like to know if this result can be extended to any metric space ? I have tried using the property of the distance function but I was not successfull, here is my attempt.</s>

Consider $(X,d)$ a metric space and $B(X_0, r)$.

Then for all $s\in[0,1]$ : $d(s(X_1-X_0) + (1-s)(X_2-X_0), X_0)\leq d(s(X_1-X_0) + (1-s)(X_2-X_0), s(X_1-X_0)) + d(s(X_1-X_0), X_0)$

and get stuck here because I don't see any property that could help me at this point, obviously I have tried to do something the triangle inequality but was not successfull. Any idea please ? I think I am missing something

Thank you a lot !

**EDIT** : The question is not correct put in this way since we can define plenty of metric space where the notion of convexity has no meaning. We need to consider metric space over a vector space as did Esgeriath in his answer.

Thus the question is the following : Is a ball in a metric space over a vector space convex ?

**Thanks to Esgeriath and geetha290krm for their helps.**

Comment: **The question has no meaning**. Convexity is defined in vector spaces. There is no notion of linear combinatioins in a metric space.

Comment: @geetha290krm While blocking on my argument I wondered if the structure of metric space was sufficient in addition but I did not go further! I made a small simple example of a 3 elements metric space with the discrete metric, indeed I can't define any notion of convexity on it. Thanks for your comment.  Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, balls in metric spaces over vector spaces don't have to be convex.

For example: consider $\mathbb R^2$ with metric
$$
d(x, y) = \cases{ \|x\| +\|y\| \quad\text{ when $x, y$ and $0$ are not colinear}\\
\|x-y\|\quad\text{otherwise}}
$$

In this metric space, we have
$$B((0,1), 2) = \{(x,y): x^2+y^2<1\} \cup \{0\}\times[0, 3)$$
is not convex.

Comment: You are totally right !  But I am afraid that I was much more confused than your question implied: I didn't want to give any additional structure to $X$ other than that of a metric space. So the problem is immediate in what I was trying to do and was mentioned in the comment. Thanks for this nice example !

Comment: It may be worth to take a note, that this example is not topological vector space, despite being topological space and vector space. Addition of vectors is not continuous (consider $\frac 1 n e_1$ converging to $0$, and $e_2 + \frac 1 n e_1$ not being Cauchy sequence)